# Is there a proper, general umbrella term for component combinations (circuit patterns) like the voltage divider and bridge circuits?

Tags: circuit-design

I am looking for a proper general umbrella term for these "building blocks" that are combinations of connections and components that may work as modularized units that may be combined together top create useful circuits. I am looking for a reference, source, or book to such circuit patterns as well.

Said building block examples include:

- voltage dividers
- current sense
- Wheatstone bridge

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are going to find what you are looking for. Although there are many of these terms (e.g. Colpitts oscillator, comparator, flip-flop,  current mirror etc.) they arose as new circuit configurations were invented.  Also, there are many variations of each type eg. there are many types of bridge circuits. But these are just for convenience when describing general circuits. It is similar to the building industry which uses terms like floors, doors, windows, joists, etc. to describe construction elements.

Comment: Part of a circuit is often called a network.

Comment: In chemistry, the general term for all the different combinations of atoms that comprise different arrangements and moieties is referred to as "chemical species".

I think the term may be "topologies".

Comment: A voltage divider is a "circuit pattern" or a "circuit topology" that is used and reused like a building block for a circuit. So, I'm looking for the proper term for "circuit pattern" or "circuit topology."

Comment: You said "Circuit configurations"--that's the sort of phrase I'm looking for.

Comment: @PrashanthC In what context are you describing - if "Circuit Configuration" is adequate, what more do you need? Most people would simply shorten that to "Circuits" in any conversation, and both parties would know what that means.

Comment: @PrashanthC Perhaps `functional circuit graph` or `circuit function graph` could be invented for you. The basic idea is that its about circuits and not something else, so `circuit` is included; that it is about functional blocks which perform specific functions but where there is more than one way to achieve that function, so `functional` is included; that it is about a specific directed graph structure that meets that function, so `graph` is included. If it catches on, I'll have to copyright and trademark the darned thing so I can retire my family. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no common or accepted answer from people with expertise. The closest phrase was "functional blocks".